# Anchor link stuck in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor, accordion

I'm using a javascript accordion plugin, but the disadvantage of this is I need to scroll to the individual sections whenever the page load.

so what I do is to create anchor link for each section, there are total 101 anchor links. If I want to access a certain section then I will just use:

```
http://wthdesign.net/test/tokl/101-things.html#65
http://wthdesign.net/test/tokl/101-things.html#25
http://wthdesign.net/test/tokl/101-things.html#99
```

.
.
.
etc

It will automatically scroll to the desire section, IE and Chrome work fine, but I have problems with Firefox, it seems like whenever I open an anchor link, it will forever get stuck in the 5th section.

I try to tweak the javascript but still no use....

This is the javascript plugin:
http://wthdesign.net/test/tokl/js/jquery.nestedAccordion.js

The Javascript I have added to bypass the current plugin's restriction (to respond to anchor link):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
          $(".accordion .outer").css("display", "block");
          console.log("url with anchor");

    } else 
          {
          //$(".accordion .outer").css("display", "none");
          console.log("url without anchor");
          }
});

</script>
```

I just realize the reason it will **stuck on 5th section is because Firefox has fix its  original height(without anchor), like so:
    http://wthdesign.net/test/tokl/101-things.html

Let's say the original container height is 2965px, so the max height it will scroll is 2965px and nothing beyond that....

Any solution for this? Many thanks in advance....

Comment: how are we supposed to help without seeing your javascript code...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've added the javascript in my original post. Thanks for the help